# Data Export in Essbase

Tags: rules, hyperion, essbase, data-export

I took data Export of a database and the export should be saved in the according app or essbase server. The problem here is I am unable to find the extracted data. Somewhere they must have been stored. Since I could execute those calculations but when opening in loadrules I cannot find them

Answer (score 0):

If you used a Rule File and was successful, then the data is already stored in the cube.

To retrieve the data you must use smartview or a predefined web form.

Answer (score 0):

The data for the Essbase export is stored on the Oracle Home directory of the Essbase (database) server where you also can find the page (.pag), index (.idx) and outline (.otl) files.

Essbase load scripts look for data on the Essbase Application Server. You need to transfer the data first from the Essbase server to the Essbase Application Server or make a network link.

side-note:
It looks like you are trying to move data back-and-forth from one cube to another cube (talking about exporting and loading). If that's the case, you'd better use the function #XREF or #XWRITE (last one is better).

Answer (score 0):

If you have executed a DATAEXPORT command, default export location is inside $ARBORPATH/app, basically inside the Essbase application folder.

When executing the command, you can actually specify a full path for the target file (inside the local server, or external location if you use UNC paths).

You can refer on the details on the command reference from the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/dataexport.html

Thanks.